# Python idiom for iterating over changing list

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there a better (more obvious/idiomatic) way in python to write an equivalent of

```
index = 0
while index < len(some_list):
    do_some_stuff(some_list[index]) # may have many side effects
    if delete_element(some_list[index]):
        del some_list[index]
    else:
        index += 1
```

or the dictionary equivalent of this for dictionaries? Dict/list comprehension is not a thing, because the result of `delete_element` might depend on  `do_some_stuff`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If order doesn't matter, you can enumerate backwards so that deletes don't mess up the part of the list you haven't processed yet.

```
for i, item in enumerate(reversed(somelist), -len(somelist)+1):
    do_some_stuff(item)
    if delete_element(item):
        del somelist[-i]
```

If order does matter, reverse the list, do this trick then reverse it again. That'll confuse 'em!

Depending on the situation, you could replace the item with a marker like None. Either strip it out later or have other places this list is used chack None.

```
for i, item in enumerate(somelist)):
    do_some_stuff(item)
    if delete_element(item):
        somelist[i] = None

somelist = [item for item in somelist if item]
```

Comment: Your `enumerate` call won't generate indexes that match your reversed values (`somelist[-len(somelist)+1]` is `somelist[0]`). You probably want `enumerate(reversed(somelist), 1)` followed later by `del somelist[-index]`.

Comment: @Blckknght - your right, I meant to use abs(i). enumerate doesn't count backwards, so the trick is to start negative and let it go to zero. But, as you say, using the negative index deletes the wrong value. - fixed in the code.

Comment: Ah, that does work better. However, I'd use `-i` rather than `abs(i)` as the latter does a check to see what sign the value has, which you don't need (you always want to negate the existing value).

Comment: @Blckknght - changed that too. Cuts a sweet .00000003 s per loop (smile).

Comment: Given my unstated requirement of modifying the list in-place, this answer fits best. It also teaches me the nice trick of passing a second argument to enumerate.

Answer (score 3):

You might break up the operations into two separate loops, and use a list comprehension for the second part.

```
for value in some_list:
    do_some_stuff(value)

some_list = [value for value in some_list if not delete_element(value)]
```

Another solution would be to iterate over a copy of the list, and use `enumerate` to keep track of the indices without having to maintain a counter by hand.

```
for index, value in enumerate(some_list[::-1]):
    do_some_stuff(value)
    if delete_element(value):
        del some_list[-index - 1]
```

You'd want to iterate backwards so you don't have to adjust `index` for the deleted elements.

Comment: `enumerate` counts up from zero, even when you call it on a reversed iterator. You need to use `del some_list[-index-1]` so the deleted indexes count down along with the items.

Answer (score 0):

you could even, assuming that `do_some_stuff` returns `item`, do something like:

```
res = [item for item in some_list if not delete_element(do_some_stuff(item))]
```

Answer (score 0):

The no-nonsense way is to use a generator:

```
def do_stuff_and_filter_items(items):
    for item in items:
        do_some_stuff(item)
        if not delete_element(item):
            yield item
```

Then to get an iterable:

```
items = do_stuff_and_filter_items(items)
```

or to get a list:

```
items = list(do_stuff_and_filter_items(items))
```

or to overwrite the old list:

```
items[:] = do_stuff_and_filter_items(items)
```